# Как, в Node.js, перенаправить параметры из GET запроса в новый GET запрос и отправить его на сервер?

Tags: node.js

С сервера приходит GET запрос вида:

```
http://qwe.rt/?foo=bar
```

Необходимо извлечь параметр **bar** из GET запроса, и составить новый GET запрос для отправки на сервер. Как это сделать в Node.js?
В данный момент есть сервер, который слушает порт, принимает запрос и выводит его на консоль.

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  console.log(request.url);
  response.end();
}).listen(8888);

console.log("Server has started");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого в [модуле HTTP](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html) есть функция [http.request(options[, callback])](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback) с полным примером в документации. Вам остается только переделать его под GET запрос.

```
http = require("http");

var options = {
  hostname: 'www.google.com',
  port: 80,
  path: '/upload',
  method: 'GET'
};

var req = http.request(options, (res) => {
  console.log(`STATUS: ${res.statusCode}`);
  console.log(`HEADERS: ${JSON.stringify(res.headers)}`);
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', (chunk) => {
    console.log(`BODY: ${chunk}`);
  });
  res.on('end', () => {
    console.log('No more data in response.')
  })
});

req.on('error', (e) => {
  console.log(`problem with request: ${e.message}`);
});


req.write("");
req.end();
```

Для парсинга пути входящего запроса есть [модуль URL](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html)